# How does aqueous ammonia react with hypochlorous acid in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, amines

Here is what I have so far:
$$\ce{NH3 + HOCl -> NH2Cl + H2O}$$
Since ammonia reacts with hypochlorous acid to form the chloramine $\ce{NH2Cl}$.
But I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: This is correct according to the Wikipedia entry on Chloramine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, aqueous ammonia will react with hypochlorous acid to form [chloramine gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloramine) as suggested by @Waylander. You can also check [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/2ps8k7/ammonium_hypochlorite/).

I am assuming this is an exercise question. **Do not try to attempt this reaction** if you are not an experienced chemist as it can also produce deadly byproducts like chlorine gas, hydrazine, dichloroamine and probably nitrogen trichloride. **Chloramine is itself poisonous.**

Comment: +1 once when was in graduate school one of the campus custodians told me that he had tried to put ammonia and chlorine bleach together in his cleaning solution and it knocked him out. I promptly got religion about household chemicals.